# Xpages Iphone Mobile Web App leaves app when opening pdf attachment

Tags: xpages

I have a Mobile Web app (for iphone) based on the Mobile controls of the Xpages extension library.
In the app the user can search for pdf and other files in the nsf files.
When the user clicks on a a filename in a view , I calculate the link like : servername/nsffilename.nsf/O/id/$FILE/filename
This opens the correct pdf file, but the user then leaves the app.
I would like to stay in the app.

I tried it with iFrames, which works fine in some browsers (IE), but not on the iphone (it only displays the first page , no way for scrolling in the pdf, no way to save the pdf file)

I also tried the download control ; but here also the user is leaving the webapp on the iphone

For an image we have a image placeholder , is something similar possible for pdf files ? a pdf placeholder ?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is standard mobile web app behaviour, nothing to do with XPages. By defalt the iphone pdf viewer registers its self to handle those file types. As you have mentioned an iFrame would work to display it (wit issues) but there is no in built XPage control to hande this.

Comment: Simon,
I found an interesting javascript project called pdf.js (https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) It seems to render the pdf files to Html5 , and seems to run fine on the Iphone.(I tested the example) The problem is , I don't know how to use it in an xpage.

Comment: took a quick look, doesn't seem to be a lot of instructions to come with it. The was a link to an example on their home page.

Xpages doesn't prevent you from adding raw html instead of XPages controls, just means you loose a lot of XPage functionality as they won't be XPage controls. Try drag and drop an example and see if it works. (modifying the javascript resource paths obviously)

Seems like a long / complicated way around dealing with standard iPhone web app support however, most users would be familiar with this happening on a web page and used to it